# Show that $\{ \bigcup_{a \in D} E_a: D \subset \{0, 1\}^n \}$ is closed under complements

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{E} = \{A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n\} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$.

Show that
$$K = \{ \bigcup_{a \in D} E_a: D \subset \{0, 1\}^n \}$$
is closed under complements, where $E_a = A_1^{a_1} \cap A_2^{a_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_n^{a_n}$, $a = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in \{0, 1\}^n$ and
$$A^a = A, a = 0, \quad A^a = A^c, a = 1$$

It is agreed that $\bigcup_{a \in \emptyset} E_a = \emptyset$.

I've showed that $K$ es a Ring of subsets of $X$.

EDIT 1:

I tried to show that $X \in K$ and for $D = \{a: a \in \{0,1\}^n\}$ it follows that $\bigcup_{a \in D} E_a = X$. But I cannot find the correct way to prove it.

Comment: The complement of $\bigcup_{a \in D} E_a$ is $\bigcup_{a \in D^{c}} E_a$

Comment: @geetha290krm Didn't see it. Appreciate it.